# How to install a iphone app in device creating provisioning account in apple developer site?

Tags: iphone

I have developed an app in xcode. Now I need to install it in iphone device so that I can test it. But I am not getting any idea how to do that as i am very new to this field. I want to install it creating provisioning account in apple developer's site (As by instruction). Please I need a step by step guidance how to do that. I stuck here for a long time. Please refer if you have any link or tutorial. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Everything explained in detail
Hope this helps you

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2

Answer (score 3):

Always try to read and use the Apple developer website to do it.

You can start from [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)

However I'm writing down the steps in detail.

Here are the details that you must do for deploy an IPA to IPhone/IPAD.

```
Create Developer account and Developer Certificate
Create  Key-chain certificate
Adding a Device
Create  App IDs
Create  Provisioning profiles
Build your App using the created Developer Certificate & Provisioning profiles.
```

**Create Developer account and Developer Certificate**

Step1: go to the site http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/

Step2: Please click on the ‘Enroll Now’ button

Step3: A window will appear with some info and a Continue button.Click Continue button

Step4: Another window will appear that ask "Are you new or a registered Apple developer?" .

Step5:  Please choose the proper option (let consider we registered Apple developer earlier).

Step6: There is another window which will ask your role. it may be a Individual or Company.

Step7: Select proper option and Sign-In with your Apple ID.

**Create  Key-chain certificate**

Step8: After Signed up , you have to use the ‘Keychain Access’ tool.
           You can search "Keychain" in the Finder search location and double click the displayed file.
           This will be used to authenticate your computer.

Step9: Click on the Keychain Access menu-->Certificate Assistance -->Request a certificate from Certificate Authority.

Step10: A new window will appear with the Email address,common name etc.. sections.

Step11:Type in the email address you used for your apple developer certificate in the ‘user email address’ field.

Step12: Use any one name as Common Name.

Step13: Click ‘Saved to disk’  button.

Step14:Another widow will appear with two combo boxes.they are Key size and Algorithm.

Step15:Select 2048 as Key Size and RSA for the Algorithm

Step16:Hit Continue button. This will generate the key and save it to the location you specified.

Step17:Click ‘Done’ in the next window.

Step18: Please visit http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action

Step19:You can see a Table of contents as Home,Certificates,Devices, App IDs,Provisioning, Distribution on left side of the window.

Step20:Click on Certificates and click on the ‘Add Certificate’ button.

Step21:Click on the ‘Choose File’ button and locate your certificate file that you saved earlier, and hit the submit button.

Step22:after you hit submit, an email will be sent to the email address you specified in the Certificate Authority (CA) request form from Keychain Access.

Step23: Open you mail account and  approve the request.

Step24:The Approval status will display in the developer site Certificates section.

Step25: After your approval, download the certificate using download button and save the certificate to a location

Step26:Double click on the file and you will see a dialog window which will ask a permission to add the certificate to the key chain..

Step27:Click ‘OK’.  This will install your iPhone Development Certificate in your Keychain.

**Adding a Device**

Step28: iPhone developer program allow you to have up to 100 devices per team.
             To register a device you have the Uniques Device Identification (UDID) number. This can be found in Xcode.

Step29:Connect your device with machine, and then open XCode-->Window-->Organizer.

Step30:A window will appear with the name of your device in the ‘Devices’ list on the left.

Step31: Click on the device name and copy the identifier string from the Summary tab.

Step32: Now we are going to add a device.Go to the Developer.Apple site which we signed-in earlier.

Step33: Click on ‘Devices’ and click on ‘Add Devices’.

Step34:Provide you device name  and Device ID that you have copied identifier string from XCode-->Window-->Organizer  .

Step35: In order to obtain provisioning profiles, you will first need to create an App ID. The App ID allows an application to communicate  It can also be used to share
              keychain information, such as passwords, between a suite of applications.

Step36:To create a new App ID, click on the ‘New App ID’ button in the ‘App ID’ section of the program portal.

Step37:An App ID consists of a 10 character “Bundle Seed ID” prefix generated by Apple and a “Bundle Identifier” suffix that is created by the Team Admin in the Program                 Portal. An App ID could look like the following example: 9F456G1234.com.apple.YourApplication or 9F456G1234.com.YourApplication.

Step38: Fill all required info and click Submit button.

**Create  Provisioning profiles**

There are three types of provisioning profiles

They are:

```
 Ad Hoc
 Development
 Distribution.
```

**Note**: The Ad Hoc and Distribution provisioning profiles are not available when running the trial version . If you are running the trial version, you should build with the Developer's provisioning profile.

Step37:To create it,Click on the "iPhone Developer Program Portal" in the Developer.Apple site, on the right side of the page, under "iPhone Developer Program".

Step38:Click on "Provisioning" on the left side of the page.

Step39:Click on the "New Profile" button on the top right, while under the development tab.

Step40:Enter a profile name, pick the certificate you would like to verify the profile with, select the App ID for this profile to be associated with and then choose which                     devices you'd like the profile to support.

Step41: Click submit.

**Build your App using the created Developer Certificate & Provisioning profiles.**

Here is the details to install the Provisioning profile after  added new devices.

Step 1: Go to the Developer.Apple site URL: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Step2: Log - in with your User Name and Password

Step3: Click iOS Dev Center tab .You can see the iOS Developer Program section on right side of the window.

Step4: You can see a tab named as "iOS Provisioning Portal" under the iOS Developer Program section.

Step5: Click the tab.You can see a Table of contents as Home,Certificates,Devices, App IDs,Provisioning, Distribution on left side of the window.You can see the newly added devices under Devices -->Available Devices section.

Step6: Go to Provisioning Tab-->Profiles. You can see the Provisioning profile there Status as Active.

Step7: Click the download button corresponding to the Provisioning profile name and the file will be in your Downloads folder after downloaded successfully.

Step8: Open Your Xcode interface and go to Window-->Organizer.

Step9:Click the Organizer and you can see the Organizer window appeared.

Step10: Double click the downloaded provisioning file. You can see the Profining profile in Organizer window Developer profile tab.

Step11: Also you can see Include number of device in Provisioning Profiles-->Included Devices section.

Step12: Close the Organizer window and go to the Xcode-->Project-->EditActiveTarget "Your Project" tab.

Step13: Switch to the Build section and serach "Code Singing Identity" in the search area.

Step14: You can see the Code signing section in the window and set the Code Signing Identity and Any IOS as your provisioning profile name.

Step15: Close the Window ,go to Build menu  and clean all Targets of your project using the Clean All Target Option.

Step16: Build and Run the Application.

**Steps to Create an IPA from Xcode 4.3**

Step1: set your project bundle Identifier name and deployment target in build settings.

```
              to do this,please click on your project and click target-->summary tab.
```

Step2: Navigate to the Build tab from the same above window and set your Base SDK ,IOS deployment target,target device family.

Step3: In the scheme drop-down on the top right of the IDE ,select iOs device.

Spep4: In the scheme editor window , select the "Archive" scheme in the left and change the build configuration settings to release.

```
             to do this,please click on X-code menu:Product -->Edit Schema
```

Step5:  Then go to X-code menu:Product and select Archive.

Step6: Application will start building when done the above action and will appear a Organizer window when the build process is get done.

```
        if the Organizer window doesn't appeared, please go to X-code menu: Window -->Organizer
```

Step7: Organizer window will appear with the Application name and created date &time. please enter the proper comment .

Step8:Click Distribute button.

Step9:A window will appear and choose the "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" option.

Step10: Click Next button.

Step11: Choose your Code signing identity and click Next button.

Step12: A save window will appear after teh Next buton clicked. Choose your location and Enter your IPA name .

Step13: Click Ok. You should able to see the IPA in system saved path.

Step14:Install the IPA to your device through iTunes

Answer (score 0):

There is step by step instructions on the apple developer site.

you need to create and app id, create a provisioning profile based of that id, install that onto your device with your developer certificate and make sure the app id matches the one in the app itself.

Then build the app for release, take the app and place it into itunes and sync with your device